# Weird filter size for airconditioner

Tags: air-conditioning, filter, measurement

I have a weird size air-conditioner filter that is **414 x 544 mm**, which is a little over 16" and a little over 21".

When I go to to the hardware store here in Canada, they carry all sorts of filter sizes, but nothing that matches my filter, so I had to cut and tape one up.

Also, when the label says 16" on a filter, it is actually less than 16" for the product? Very confusing.

What is going on here?

Did I end up with a European filter in Canada, maybe? Or is something else going on?

The brand name on it is **Carrier** and model number is FB4CNF036.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The site filterbuy.com does have filters that are a little over 16x21 in, e.g., 16.25 x 21.25 x 1 inch.

What is the thickness of your filter, 1 inch, 2 inch, etc.?

Comment: Mine is 7/8" but with some luck the 1" filters could fit perhaps. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Don't get a filter that is too restrictive. It would have too much resistance to air flow.